# Can I use ExpressionEngine core for a portfolio site

Tags: license, core

I need to CMS-ify my friends design portfolio.

Can I use expressionengine core, or would I need a licenced? I've had a look at the terms and conditions for the Core version but I'm still not quite sure.

Really hope I can use ee, absolutely love working with it.

Thanks
dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably her portfolio site is there to sell her services, so that would qualify it as commercial use. Feel free to email EllisLab, but I'm pretty sure that this falls outside of the intent of the "core" license.

From the EE [software license](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/license.html):

> Users of the Core License may use the Software only on a website engaging in personal, non-commercial, or non-profit activities.

Comment: this is the site http://www.luckydave.co.uk/

Comment: Looks commercial to me. Simple question: is the purpose of the site to generate money for a business (directly or indirectly)? If yes, then you have to pay for a license.

Comment: waaaa :( !!! thanks for your reply, muchly appreciated